KeyError on Pandas
I have a code in python like this :
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='GCIF_NO', how='left')


def TAB_Online(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['GCIF_NO']):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

and then after that i build a code like this :
df1['TAB_Online'] = merged_df.apply(TAB_Online)

but it return an error like this :
KeyError: 'GCIF_NO'

after that i check whether GCIF_NO available or not on the dataframe with a code like this :
# Example check to verify column existence
if 'GCIF_NO' in df1.columns:
    print("Column 'GCIF_NO' exists in df1")
else:
    print("Column 'GCIF_NO' does not exist in df1")

and it return Column 'GCIF_NO' exists in df1.
so where's my problem?

Your code, which uses func apply to detect isnull and assign a value, isn't efficient, and it's not how we typically solve problems in Pandas.

If you're still wondering why you're getting a KeyError, it's because you need to specify axis when applying func apply to a data frame(apply your func as row by row when axis=1.), but I'd recommend asking with [mre] what you want rather than modifying your code to apply apply to modify axis.

since im new in python, i dont know where my wrong at?

To summarise, it's a problem with axis(need axis=1) when use apply function, but solving this will introduce new problems(inefficient and so on), so read notice([mre]) and ask questions with example.
